# Adding comma separated strings to an ArrayList and vice versa

Tags: java, arraylist, csv

How to add a comma separated string to an ArrayList? My string "returnedItems" could hold 1 or 20 items which I'd like to add to my ArrayList "selItemArrayList".

After the ArrayList has been populated, I'd like to later iterate through it and format the items into a comma separated string with no spaces between the items.

Comment: what data returnedItems consists of? Is like "test,test2,test567" and so on?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, yes its consists of "carrots, onions, garlic" etc..

Comment: Though keep in mind things can get rather more complicated if the strings themselves can have commas in them. (see my answer below)

Answer (score 16):

```
String returnedItems = "a,b,c";
List<String> sellItems = Arrays.asList(returnedItems.split(","));
```

Now iterate over the list and append each item to a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String item: sellItems){
    if(sb.length() > 0){
        sb.append(',');
    }
    sb.append(item);
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Since Java 8 you can join with: String joined = String.join(",", sellItems);

Answer (score 9):

One-liners are always popular:

```
Collections.addAll(arrayList, input.split(","));
```

Answer (score 5):

[`split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and [`asList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) do the trick:

```
String [] strings = returnedItems.split(",");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strings);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple one-liner:

```
selItemArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(returnedItems.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
```

Of course it will be more complex if you have entries with commas in them.

Comment: Great! When I store a List as String with aList.toString() elements in list are separed by comma and with a white space after the comma. Whit this RegExp on Split I can put in List again correct Items!

Answer (score 2):

This can help:

```
for (String s : returnedItems.split(",")) {
    selItemArrayList.add(s.trim());
}

//Shorter and sweeter
String [] strings = returnedItems.split(",");
selItemArrayList = Arrays.asList(strings);

//The reverse....

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Iterator<String> iter = selItemArrayList.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (sb.length() > 0) 
        sb.append(",");
    sb.append(iter.next());
}

returnedItems = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the strings themselves can have commas in them, things get more complicated.  Rather than rolling your own, consider using one of the many open-source CSV parsers.  While they are designed to read in files, at least OpenCSV will also parse an individual string you hand it.

- [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/)
- [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)
- [Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/)
- [OsterMiller CSV](http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the individual items aren't quoted then:

```
 QString str = "a,,b,c";

 QStringList list1 = str.split(",");
 // list1: [ "a", "", "b", "c" ]
```

If the items are quoted I'd add "[]" characters and use a JSON parser.

Comment: Oops!! That was Qt.  But I'm sure there's the equivalent in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `split()` method on String to convert the String to an array that you could loop through.

Although you might be able to skip the looping and parsing with a regular expression to remove the spaces using replaceAll() on a String.

Answer (score 0):

```
String list = "one, two, three, four";
String[] items = list.split("\\p{Punct}");
List<String> aList = Arrays.asList(items);
System.out.println("aList = " + aList);
StringBuilder formatted = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    formatted.append(items[i].trim());
    if (i < items.length - 1) formatted.append(',');
}

System.out.println("formatted = " + formatted.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.common.base.*;

Iterable<String> items = Splitter.on(",").omitEmptyStrings()
                                 .split("Mango,Apple,Guava");

// Join again!
String itemsString = Joiner.join(",").join(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String csv = "Apple, Google, Samsung";
```

step one : converting comma separate String to array of String

```
String[] elements = csv.split(",");
```

step two : convert String array to list of String

```
 List<String> fixedLenghtList = Arrays.asList(elements);
```

step three : copy fixed list to an ArrayList
ArrayList listOfString = new ArrayList(fixedLenghtList);

```
System.out.println("list from comma separated String : " + listOfString);
```

System.out.println("size of ArrayList : " + listOfString.size());
Output :

```
list of comma separated String : [Apple, Google, Samsung]


size of ArrayList : 3
```