# How to add a comma at the end of every element in ArrayList On Android

Tags: android, arraylist

In my application I want use this [Library](https://github.com/adroitandroid/ChipCloud) for show `ArrayList` items.
**My ArrayList from server:**

```
"genres": [
      "Action",
      " Comedy",
      " Family"
    ]
```

I write below code for show Items:

```
private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings = serialResponse.getData().getGenres();
private List<String> cloudChipList = new ArrayList<>();

for (String str : mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings) {
    cloudChipList.add(str);

    if (cloudChipList.size() > 0) {
       infoSerialFrag_GenreChips.addChip(str);
    }
}
```

**Gives oputput as:**

> Ganre : Action Comedy Family

**But I want it like this :**

> Ganre : Action , Comedy , Family

**Please help me with my above codes**, I am amateur and need this help, please help me with my above codes. Thanks all <3

Comment: Suggestion don't save ',' in array list instead get the genre and append ',' at the end. Also put check whether the element is last to prevent last ',' to be printed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this using for loop like this:

**EDITED :**

```
private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings;
    private List<String> cloudChipList = new ArrayList<>();

    mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings = serialResponse.getData().getGenres();

    for (String str : mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings) {
        cloudChipList.add(str);
    }
    if (cloudChipList.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cloudChipList.size(); i++) {

            if (i == (cloudChipList.size() - 1)) //true only for last element
                infoSerialFrag_GenreChips.add(cloudChipList.get(i));

            else
                infoSerialFrag_GenreChips.add(cloudChipList.get(i) + ","); //this will execute for 1st to 2nd last element
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you edit your code with my above codes? please send to me full code with my above codes. please I really need your help

Comment: In which arraylist you want that colon separated strings? In cloudChipList or in infoSerialFrag_GenreChips?

Comment: infoSerialFrag_GenreChips, please help me my friend. I am amateur and really need your helps. please

Comment: Jong, your requirements are not clear so not getting exactly what you want. Hope my edited answer helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TextUtils.join(",", yourList);`

Comment: can you edit your code and send to me full code? please my friend

Answer (score 0):

Do it the old Java 6 way and add the comma yourself unless its the last element in the list.

See the following example:

```
private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings = serialResponse.getData().getGenres();
private List<String> cloudChipList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length; i++) {

    String str = mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i];

    if (i + 1 < mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length) str = str + ", ";

    cloudChipList.add(str);

    if (cloudChipList.size() > 0) {
       infoSerialFrag_GenreChips.addChip(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: if use this, show me this : Ganre : Action , Comedy , Family , !!!! I don't want show , to lasted of list

Answer (score 0):

> The java.util.ArrayList.add(int index, E elemen) method inserts the
>   specified element E at the specified position in this list.It shifts
>   the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent
>   elements to the right (will add one to their indices).

**Edited**

```
 if (cloudChipList.size() > 0) 
 {
        if(cloudChipList.get(cloudChipList.size()-1).contains(","))
        {
            infoSerialFrag_GenreChips.add(str);
        }
        else
        {
            infoSerialFrag_GenreChips.add(str+",");
        } 
 }
```

**OP will be**

> Ganre : Action , Comedy , Family

Comment: if use this, show me this : Ganre : Action , Comedy , Family , !!!! I don't want show , to lasted of list

Comment: @Jong get last value `infoSerialFrag_GenreChips.get(infoSerialFrag_GenreChips.size()-1);` Then remove (String remove) `,`

Comment: where add your code? can you edit your answer and send to me full code with my above codes ? please man, I really need your help. please

Comment: @Jong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096845/adding-comma-separated-strings-to-an-arraylist-and-visa-versa

Comment: I showing this in my request response! I edit my code with your help, but show me such as this : Action , Comedy , Family , . I want Remove lasted , and show me like this : Action , Comedy , Family. how can edit my code? please help me my friend

Comment: I am amateur, can you help me with my above codes? please

Comment: I edit my code such as this :                 `for (String str : mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings) {
                    cloudChipList.add(str);
                    if (cloudChipList.size() > 0) {
                        if (cloudChipList.get(cloudChipList.size() - 1).contains(",")) {
                            infoSerialFrag_GenreChips.addChip(str);
                        } else {
                            infoSerialFrag_GenreChips.addChip(str + "  ,");
                        }
                    }
                }`   **But not work me again** and show , too lasted item

Answer (score 0):

Although it is late, just case if someone else comes to this thread...
If you are using Java 8, you can use streaming and Collectors interfaces like the following:

```
List<String> cloudChipList = new ArrayList<String>();
    cloudChipList.add("Action");
    cloudChipList.add("Comedy");
    cloudChipList.add("Family");

    String result = cloudChipList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" , ", "Genre: ", "\n"));
    System.out.println(result);
```

Here `Collectors.joining` adds delimiter, prefix and suffix to the result, but it has an option with only the delimter, too.